# Elliptic curves: about a passage in J. Silverman's "Advanced topics of elliptic curves"

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Reading the proof of the main theorem of complex multiplication for elliptic curves over number fields in J. Silverman's book *"Advanced topics of elliptic curves"* I got stuck at a passage which looks quite innocuous but which I can not provide a reasonable proof about. On page 126, proving Proposition 4.2 the following statement is given. Let $p$ be a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ which splits completely in the quadratic field extension $K$, so that $pO_{K}=\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q}$. Then it is always possible to find an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ in $O_{K}$, coprime with $pO_{K}$ and such that $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{p}$ is principal. I do not see any immediate reason why this should be true? I have found a paper by K. Conrad stating that for any $\mathfrak{a}$ in $O_{K}$ then if $\overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ is the conjugate of $\mathfrak{a}$ (the ideal of all conjugates of the elements of $\mathfrak{a}$), we have that $\mathfrak{a}\overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ is principal. This seems weaker than the statement in J. Silverman's book and still very complicated to prove. Is there any simple proof I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the question right? $pO_K$ itself is principal, so you could take $\mathfrak a=O_K$.

Comment: Thank you I was not meaning $pO_{K}$ but $\mathfrak{p}$ above $p$, I have edited the question now

Comment: Quickest, although maybe overkill, consider the ideal class of $\mathfrak p^{-1}$, Every ideal class contains infinitely many prime ideals, take any of them  (other than $\mathfrak p$ itself if $\mathfrak p^2$ is principal) for $\mathfrak a$.

Comment: It looks even easier because there was no requirement that  be prime.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I agree, there probably is an easier way. But for a book at this level, I think it's fair to use results from a first course in algbraic number theory. Also, what I wrote isn't quite right, one should take a prime ideal in the ideal class of $\mathfrak p^{-1}$ other than $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$.

Comment: Let $a\in O_K$ be such that $a\in\mathfrak p,a\not\in\mathfrak p^2,a\not\in\mathfrak q$ (CRT). Then $(a)\subseteq\mathfrak p$, so $(a)=\mathfrak a\mathfrak p$ for some $\mathfrak a$. The choice of $a$ guarantees $\mathfrak a$ is not divisible by $\mathfrak p$ or $\mathfrak q$.